# Can we generate primary keys automatically without JDBC queries or calls?

Tags: java, mysql, oracle, hibernate, primary-key

I am trying to generate alpha-numberic (e.g. TESLA1001) primary keys automatically in Hibernate. I am currently using Oracle database, so I have a JDBC call to `my_sequence.NEXTVAL` (1002) to increment number and append to the prefix (TESLA).

We are considering MySQL as an option, but they do not support sequences. So I am forced to re-write the Custom ID generation technique using JDBC call to a stored procedure.

Is there any way I can have a generic implementation to generate custom primary keys without the use of JDBC and database dependent queries? So, in future, if I need to test my application with MSSQL, I need to change my hiberate configuration only and things work fine!

Comment: You have autoIncrement with MySql

Comment: Yes, but autoincrement only works for one table, you could query the last_insert_id() from everything involved if you have several tables or you could use triggers.

Comment: Also it's not too hard to implement a sequence using a stored procedure, e.g. table sequences ( name, number) and a procedure getNext(name) which increases the number by one and returns it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you need a way to coordinate the sequence number, you'll always have to use a centralized sequence generator. An alpha-numerical primary key will perform worse on indexing than a UUID generator.

If I were you, I'd switch to [UUID identifers](http://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-and-uuid-identifiers/) which are both unique and portable across all major RDBMS.